# strategy for writing format of object to mysql table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Rails newbie here so just want to be sure I'm doing this right. I have a couple of complex relationships and would like to cache those relationships locally in the mysql row. Think a feature like facebook likes. I have this information currently in a mysql table. I was going to put in a "liked_ids" column that is text and stored as json. And then have an accessor like:

```
def likes
  str=self.liked_ids
  b=JSON.parse(str)
  return b
end
```

I have seen some people mention storing as YAML instead but there's a ton of json already being used.

And then when someone submits to the main table (say likes_users), we just add a callback that updates this json field.

Are there alternatives or does this seem like a reasonable idea?

thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [serialize](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#method-c-serialize) method to define a serialization column.
The serialization is done through YAML.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :liked_ids, Array
end

user = User.create(:liked_ids => [1, 2, 3])
User.find(user.id).liked_ids # => [1, 2, 3]
```

All there's left is to keep the column in sync via callbacks.

Comment: I've seen serialize but does that get me anything more than just dealing with json?

Comment: Saves you the trouble of serializing/deserializing the object yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a table and separate model?

User likes Post

users_posts ---> user_id, post_id

Class user has and belongs to many likes (class override to Post)

I wouldn't store relationship data as a field when you are using a relational database.

Comment: so the model is much more complex than original question and would be doing that and maintaining sync via callbacks. but agreed with your thinking.

Comment: @timpone: This isn't really more complicated, try maintaining referential integrity with a serialized column and you'll gain a better appreciation of what *complicated* means :)

Comment: something is getting lost here. this is basically caching results into a users table, keeping referential integrity in the source table. nothing more. thx